# week number from a certain date

Tags: sql, oracle

I has a following table in oracle

[image]

as you see teh start date is 04-Nov-20. I need to count 04-Nov-2021 to 10-Nov-2021 as week 1 and 11-nov-2021 to 17-Nov-2021 as Week 2 and so on. How can I achieve dis values in oracle.

using DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY game_id ORDER BY TO_CHAR(start_date, 'YYYYWW')) as num giving me output
[image]
as you can see the first week doesn't have 7 days.

Comment: Also _specify_ the expected result.

Comment: What do you expect to happen when the next year follows? Just keep on counting?

Comment: and presumably confused among 2020 and 2021, didn't you?

Comment: next year follow just keep counting

Answer (score 1):

You can check what the week number is by combining the **to_char** function with the **WW**, **W**, or **IW**.

```sql
select to_char(column,'WW') from table;
```

```
WW  Week of year (1-53) where week 1 starts on the first day of the year and continues to the seventh day of the year.
W   Week of month (1-5) where week 1 starts on the first day of the month and ends on the seventh.
IW  Week of year (1-52 or 1-53) based on the ISO standard.
```

Comment: But 2020-11-04 is Wednesday, and 2020-11-10 is Tuesday on another week. The requirement was to map them both to the same week

Comment: No, output should be week start from wed only. I am just trying to find week 1 after 1st and and so on

Answer (score 0):

By using the day difference with the first start_date per game_id.

**Via FIRST_VALUE**

> ```
> SELECT g.*
> , FLOOR((start_date-FIRST_VALUE(start_date) OVER (PARTITION BY game_id ORDER BY start_date))/7)+1 AS weeks
> FROM gamestarts g
> ORDER BY game_id, start_date;
> ```

**Or via a join on a summary**

> ```
> SELECT g.*
> , FLOOR((start_date-first_date)/7)+1 AS weeks
> FROM gamestarts g
> LEFT JOIN (
>   SELECT game_id, MIN(start_date) AS first_date
>   FROM gamestarts
>   GROUP BY game_id
> ) m ON m.game_id = g.game_id
> WHERE start_date >= date'2021-06-17'
> ORDER BY g.game_id, g.start_date;
> ```
>
> ```
> GAME_ID | START_DATE | WEEKS
> ------: | :--------- | ----:
>     899 | 2021-06-17 |     1
>     899 | 2021-06-18 |     1
>     899 | 2021-06-19 |     1
>     899 | 2021-06-20 |     1
>     899 | 2021-06-21 |     1
>     899 | 2021-06-22 |     1
>     899 | 2021-06-23 |     1
>     899 | 2021-06-24 |     2
>     899 | 2021-06-25 |     2
>     899 | 2021-06-26 |     2
> ```

Test on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=0b56a851d7478375972cdf2bea51efc5)*

Comment: It is working good, the only problem that some reason the first week doesn't have 7 days. I put the output in my question above as I can't paste the output here

Comment: @deepankarsrigyan Just to clarify, you want the dates within 7 days, but it doesn't matter what week it is, just use the first day as weekday 1?

Comment: See update.  Note that using this method that there'll be a gap in the number if more than a week is missing in the dates.

Comment: Thats spot on, however last thing. What if one of the date is missing in the sequence i think it will go on next day. I mean consider17/6 to 23/6 is first week and 19/6 is missing from data. then this will end the 1st week on 24/6 and that will spoil the result. Is there any solution for this...

Comment: This method only cares about the difference with the oldest date. So if a day is missing then it won't affect the other dates in that week. However, a window function like DENSE_RANK or FIRST_VALUE depends on what's in the resultset.  F.e. if you add a criteria `WHERE start_date > '2022-06-01'` then the number 1 will start after that date.

Comment: @deepankarsrigyan See update. The second method will return the same numbers, even if you filter on the start_date.

Comment: Thank you for your help.